# How to get interaction url request with emoji reaction on discord?

Tags: node.js, discord, bots, emoji

I am not using discord.js because my codes run on AWS lambda.
So I registered `INTERACTIONS ENDPOINT URL` on discord developer site.
And selected scopes on `OAuth2 URL Generator` like below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INZCN.png)

Inviting bot was succeeded. And then I type some message and add emoji

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWmth.png)

But when I checked logs on AWS cloudwatch, it not logged.

verify codes are written. And slash command works well. but bot not read message and emoji.

How can bot get message or emoji with discord `INTERACTIONS ENDPOINT URL`?

[image]

```js
// interactionRouter.ts
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises */
import express from 'express';
import {
  interactDiscordController,
  interactUserController,
} from '../controller/interactController';

export const interactionRouter = express.Router();

interactionRouter.post('/', interactDiscordController());
interactionRouter.get('/test', (_req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Hello from router!',
  });
});

interactionRouter.use(express.json());
interactionRouter.post('/user-info', interactUserController());


// interactionController.ts
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import DirectMessageToUserUseCaseDto from '../../../core/dto/directMessageToUserUseCaseDto';
import SetUserRoleOnDiscordDto from '../../../core/dto/setUserRoleOnDiscordDto';
import DirectMessageToUserUseCase from '../../../core/usecase/directMessageToUserUseCase';
import SetUserRoleOnDiscordUseCase from '../../../core/usecase/setUserRoleOnDiscordUseCase';

// TODO usecase inject
export const interactDiscordController =
  () => async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
      console.log(`req : `);
      console.log(req);

      const usecase = new DirectMessageToUserUseCase();
      const dto = new DirectMessageToUserUseCaseDto();
      const isDtoCreated = await dto.create(req);
      if (!isDtoCreated) {
        return res.status(400).send(false);
      }

      const result:
        | {
            status: number;
            message: string;
          }
        | { status: number; message: { type: number } } = usecase.execute(dto);
      return res.status(result.status).send(result.message);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return false;
    }
  };

//directMessageToUserUseCase.ts
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands */
import DirectMessageToUserUseCaseDto from '../dto/directMessageToUserUseCaseDto';
import nacl from 'tweetnacl';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { resolve } from 'path';
dotenv.config({
  path: resolve(__dirname, `../../.env.${String(process.env.NODE_ENV)}`),
});

export default class DirectMessageToUserUseCase {
  verify(dto: DirectMessageToUserUseCaseDto) {
    try {
      console.log(
        `DISCORD_PUBLIC_KEY ${String(process.env.DISCORD_PUBLIC_KEY)}`
      );
      console.log(`signature ${String(dto.signature)}`);
      console.log(`timestamp ${String(dto.timestamp)}`);
      const isVerified = nacl.sign.detached.verify(
        Buffer.from(dto.timestamp + dto.rawBody),
        Buffer.from(dto.signature, 'hex'),
        Buffer.from(String(process.env.DISCORD_PUBLIC_KEY), 'hex')
      );
      console.log(`isVerified ${String(isVerified)}`);
      if (!isVerified) {
        console.log('Failed verification');
        return {
          status: 401,
          message: 'invalid request signature',
        };
      }

      console.log('Handling validation test request');
      return {
        status: 200,
        message: { type: 1 },
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return {
        status: 400,
        message: 'Error handling verification',
      };
    }
  }

  execute(dto: DirectMessageToUserUseCaseDto) {
    if (dto.body === undefined) {
      return {
        status: 400,
        message: 'DM failed',
      };
    }
    console.log(`body ${JSON.stringify(dto.body)}`);
    if (
      (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev' ||
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') &&
      Number(dto.body.type) === 1
    ) {
      return this.verify(dto);
    }
    try {
      /*
    TODO
    vercel 프론트엔드 주소와 유저 id를 알려주고 주소 클릭해서 지갑 연결, id 입력하라고 DM 보낸다.
    */
      const url = 'https://www.google.com/';
      const userId: string = dto.body.user.id;
      return {
        status: 200,
        message: {
          type: 4,
          data: {
            content: `click this [link](${url}) to connect wallet and then type your user id -> ${String(
              userId
            )}`,
          },
        },
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return {
        status: 400,
        message: 'DM failed',
      };
    }
  }
}
```

When I send message or emoji on channel where the bot existing, I can not get `console.log(req)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concluded there is no emoji listening function in interaction url.
So I created [button](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components#buttons) and finally get signal that button clicked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not specified the 'MessageContent' and 'GuildMessageReactions' intents when configuring your client.

In discord.js v14 that would work like this:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
    ],
    partials: ["CHANNEL"]
});
```

Here is a list of all the gateway intents: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents